# I am not able to replace the letter in my list

Tags: python

so basically I need to make a word puzzle, and the user has 4 tries. It shoes the number of blanks(representing the number of letters) and if the user guesses a correct letter then it should replace the corresponding blank(s) with that letter.

```
def main():
    
    f = open("wp_instructions.txt" , "r")
    read = f.read()
    print(read)
    
    guesses = 4
    
    word_list = ['apple', 'banana', 'watermelon', 'kiwi', 'pineapple', 'mango']
    
    word = random.choice(word_list)
    
    list_word = list(word)
    
    blanks = len(word)
    
    word_puzzle = ["_"]*blanks
    
    new_blank = []
    
    while guesses > 0 :
    
        print("The answer so far is " , word_puzzle)
        
        user_guess = input("Guess a letter (" + str(guesses) + " guesses remaining) : ") 
        
        if user_guess in list_word :
            for i in word_puzzle :
                letter_rep = i.replace('_' , user_guess)
                word_puzzle.append(letter_rep)
        else :
            guesses -= 1
    
main()
```

[this is the expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJkgH.png)

Comment: Please post textual output as text, not an image of text.

Comment: What part of this code is attempting to replace blanks?

Answer (score 0):

A couple things are tripping you up here.

```
if user_guess in list_word :
    # If the user guess is anywhere in the word, you're running
    # this whole loop
    for i in word_puzzle :
        # This 'replace' statement runs for every 
        #letter in the current puzzle
        letter_rep = i.replace('_' , user_guess)
        # you're appending the replaced string at the end of the
        # puzzle, not replacing it in place
        word_puzzle.append(letter_rep)
```

In the spirit of helping instead of doing homework consider this algorithm-

1. create a new empty word puzzle 'new_puzzle'
2. loop over 'old_puzzle'
3. If the value of 'list_word[i]' == 'user_guess', append 'new_puzzle.append(user_guess)', else, 'new_puzzle.append(value)'
4. replace 'old_puzzle' with 'new_puzzle'
5. continue until out of guesses or no "_" left in new puzzle